# Relation tables n:n on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I have a doubt, I have two tables n: n and I want to create an additional table that stores the two ids of each table. Such as shop and product.

How do I create a store by creating an product automatically in the table shop_product?

Comment: There is no better place to find what you're looking for other than the documentation :), [eloquent-relationships#many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: What have you tried?  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
 save shop data      
                 $shop->save();
                 $shopid= $shop->id;
 after save fetch data from shop and simillarly from product

               $product->save();
               $productid= $product->id;
finally use both variables in shop_product like this
             $shop_product->shop_id= $shopid;
               $shop_product->product_id= $productid;
```

Comment: yeah if u use same method for both shop and product..means u need to create both using single form..otherwise u need to use relations